# Find all the persons which contains the provided resources

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below are the tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Person(
    PersonID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName VARCHAR(10),
    LastName VARCHAR(10));

CREATE TABLE Resources(
    ResourceID CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE PR (
    PersonID INT,
    ResourceID CHAR(3),
CONSTRAINT pkpr PRIMARY KEY (PersonID, ResourceID),
CONSTRAINT fkPersonID FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Person(PersonID),
CONSTRAINT fkResourceID FOREIGN KEY (ResourceID) REFERENCES Resources(ResourceID));


INSERT INTO Person(PersonID, FirstName, LastName) VALUES (1, 'Bill', 'Smith'),(2, 'John','Jones');
INSERT INTO Resources (ResourceID) VALUES ('ABC'),('DEF'),('HIJ');
INSERT INTO PR (PersonID, ResourceID) VALUES (1,'ABC'),(1,'DEF'),(2,'ABC'), (2,'HIJ'), (1,'HIJ');
```

How to find all the persons which has resources ('ABC', 'DEF') ?

With above inserted data it should return person Bill Smith

I am using PostgreSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select pr.personid
from pr 
where pr.resourceid in ('ABC', 'DEF')
group by pr.personid
having count(*) = 2;
```

The primary key on `pr` prevents duplicates, so `count(*)` ensures that both resources are assigned to the person.